# Listen for 500 responses on Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm listening to xhr events on a webpage, in order to catch any possible request failures. In order to listen to all of them, I'm applying this pseudo-monkey-patch:

```
var reqOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
this.addEventListener('load', function() {

console.log(this.readyState); // this is always 4, but I'm trying to 
listen for when it's not successful
console.log(this.responseText); //the respoinse

});

reqOpen.apply(this, arguments);
```

It works when there is a successful response, but other than that it won't catch anything.

Is there any way I can try to catch unsuccessful requests (specifically requests that return a 500 response?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this article:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/error_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` event only fires when a request has been successfully completed.
The [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) event will fire at every step in the process of the request.

Within that event handler, check for the `readyState` of `4`, which means the request is done, either succefully or not. Then detect if the [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) property is `500`. This property will be the HTTP response code you're looking for.

There won't be a payload, since the server couldn't send a response back, making `responseText` useless. Instead check the [`statusText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText) property to get the message that corresponds with the HTTP status.

```
var reqOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 500) {
      console.log(this.statusText);
    }
  });

  reqOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an advantage of using this over the other solution of using 'loadend'?

Comment: No, `loadend` is more specific and only fires whenever the loading ends. `readystatechange` is called multiple times and would give you more control when you need to observe more than only the `done` ready state. So `loadend` would be more optimized for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `status` in the `load` event or in `loadend` event.

Endpoint used in this demo returns a 500

```js
var reqOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  this.addEventListener('loadend', function() {
     if(this.status > 200){
        console.log('Loadend Status:', this.status)
     }      
  });
  this.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Load Status:', this.status)
  });
  reqOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}

// example making request with jQuery ajax that uses XMLHTtpRequest
$.get('https://httpstat.us/500')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any advantage of using this over the other solution of readystatechange?

Comment: readystate changes numerous times during a request, load events are only at specific points